# How to check session is alive or not using session id?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables, session-timeout, sessionid

I have scenario, where two or more users logging into the system and open an item to process some operation. If user A has opened x item then user B cannot open the same x item. I have stored the user ids in session. When user A open the x item I have stored session id of user A into database and mark x item block. Now when user B, select x item I have to check weather the session of User A is alive or not?

Answer (score 0):

use synchronous methods where only one object executes the method at a time. instead of checking user every time. 
Or 
Keep an static integer increment and decrement it when ever the user executes that piece of code or store an integer into database and check it.

Thirdly use Application object

Comment: Then how do I handle when user lost the network after opening the item?

Comment: use durable services for maintaining state in wcf even after server restarts.

Comment: but I have to clear the user selection if user lost the network. how do I check wheather user is online or not?